# Dynamically adding domains to scrapy crawlspider deny_domains list

Tags: python, scrapy

I am currently using scrapy's CrawlSpider to look for specific info on a list of multiple start_urls.  What I would like to do is stop scraping a specific start_url's domain once I've found the information I've looked for, so it won't keep hitting a domain and will instead just hit the other start_urls.

Is there a way to do this?  I have tried appending to deny_domains like so:

```
deniedDomains = []
...
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(..., deny_domains=(etc), ...)]
...
def parseURL(self, response):
    ...
    self.deniedDomains.append(specificDomain)
```

Appending doesn't seem to stop the crawling, but if I start the spider with the intended specificDomain then it'll stop as requested.  So I'm assuming that you can't change the deny_domains list after the spider's started?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this , is to maintain your own `dynamic_deny_domain` list in your Spider class :

- write a simple [Downloader Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#topics-downloader-middleware),
- it's a simple class, with one method implementation: `process_request(request, spider):`
- return [IgnoreRequest](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest)  if the request is in your `spider.dynamic_deny_domain` list, `None` otherwise.

Then add your downloaderMiddleWare to [Middleware list in scrapy settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std%3asetting-DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES) , at first position 
`'myproject.downloadermiddleware.IgnoreDomainMiddleware': 50,`

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Something ala?

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "foo"
    allowed_domains = ["example.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.org/foo/",]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(
            allow=('/foo/[^/+]',),
            deny_domains=('example.com',)),
        callback='parseURL'),
        )

    def parseURL(self, response):

        # here the rest of your code
```