# Moving onto next url if certain amount of pages have been crawled in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I've found two answers to this questions but none is working for me. Basically, I want to restrict the amount of pages crawled per domain. Here's the code in the actual crawler:

```
def parse_page(self, response)
    visited_count.append(response.url.split('/')[2])
        if visited_count.count(response.url.split('/')[2]) > 49:
            print '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'
            denied.append(response.url)
```

and Custom Middleware:

```
class IgnoreDomain(object):
    def process_requests(request, spider):
        if request in spider.denied:
            return IgnoreRequest()
        else:
            return None
```

Of course middleware is mentioned in settings.
I would really appreciate if you could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Post the complete middleware class and not just part of it

Comment: Oh that's probably what I did wrong - that's all of it haha. Followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657006/dynamically-adding-domains-to-scrapy-crawlspider-deny-domains-list

Comment: So its solved now?

Comment: No, I followed the answer in the link and it says to do only that.

Comment: No, that is not the way you should do. In your `process_requests` you need to get the url from the request object and then extract the domain name from it. Maintain a dictionary of urls from that domain. Once it exceeds the limit then you want to return IgnoreRequests

Comment: `def process_requests(request, spider):
     if request.url.split('/')[2] in spider.denied:
        return IgnoreRequest()
     else:         
       return None` - this isn't working either. And I've change the `denied.append()` to get url.split('/')[2]  only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said `I want to restrict the amount of pages crawled per domain` ...

Do this, create `counter` in your spider

```
class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    counter = {}
    #counter will have values like {'google.com': 4, 'website.com': 2} etc
```

At top of your middleware file write this

```
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest

import logging

class YourMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):

        domain = tldextract.extract(request.url)[1]
        logging.info(spider.counter)
        if domain not in spider.counter:
               pass #keep scraping this link
        else:
               if spider.counter[domain] > 5:
                    raise IgnoreRequest()
               else:
                    pass #keep processing this request

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):    

        domain = tldextract.extract(request.url)[1]

        if domain not in spider.counter:
               spider.counter[domain] = 1
        else:
               spider.counter[domain] = spider.counter[domain] + 1

        return response
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution. Just to clarify couple of things - these functions should go into the custom middleware, right? If so, I get an error that counter variable is not defined - where should I define it?

Comment: thanks for the update. Unfortunately, wherever I define `counter` I still get an error that it is not defined

Comment: where you get that error in which file? ... please show me full code I will help you

Comment: So I create a custom middleware class where I put your functions:
`class IgnoreDomain(object):`. In my spider file, in the spider class, I define `counter = {}`. The error occurs `    if domain not in counter:
NameError: global name 'counter' is not defined`

Comment: @TomDom did you define `counter = {}` in your Spider? and then access your variable in middleware like `spider.counter`

Comment: That seems to work, thank you! I got another error tho: `AssertionError: Middleware IgnoreDomain.process_response must return Response or Request, got <type 'NoneType'>`

Comment: I added `return response` at the end of process_response and it doesn't raise an error anymore. However the crawler doesn't stop after 5 pages as defined

Comment: LOL, the code I wrote was sort of `pseudo code` please read doc of `process_response` https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response ... anyways, please read my answer again, I have updated it, and please accept and upvote my answer if it helped

Comment: I've used it from the beginning, unfortunately the crawler doesn't stop.

Comment: @TomDom see my updated answer now, see `logging.info(spider.counter)` ... and see in your terminal if `counter` variable is being updated properly...

Comment: I think I figured out what's wrong with the code. `if spider.counter[domain] > 5:` rather than `=.